# Get data from FarPoint Spread control running in another application

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation, farpoint-spread

I'm attempting to write a application in C# utilizing the Microsoft UI Automation framework. The application to be controlled uses a component called "FarPoint Spread". It's easy enough to automate the rest of the application (e.g. its WinForms controls), but I can't seem to do anything with the FarPoint Spread control.

I'm still very green when it comes to programming. I've got just the basics of C# and UI automation down. Just need someone to point me to the information I need to have to automate this Spread component (if that's even possible). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the grid rendering in Spread is written probably using custom code, and it's not equipped with what UI Automation expects.

I have tested the Sample Explorer provided by GrapeCity here (http://spread.grapecity.com/Pages/Demos/) with UI Automation's Inspect tool, and once you get to the data grid itself, there's nothing shown in Inspect.

There's also this topic in GrapeCity's forums:
[Is Spread even supported in coded UI test](http://sphelp.grapecity.com/forums/topic/is-spread-even-supported-in-coded-ui-test/) which clearly states (2 years ago) it's not supported (as you known VS Coded UI also uses UI Automation as the underlying technology).

So, I guess it's not possible to automate Spread using UI automation (maybe they have their own system, you'd have to contact them).

Comment: Well that's unfortunate, but thank you for taking the time to answer!